# Running xdebug debugger from Netbeans opens incorrect page

Tags: netbeans, wamp, xdebug, wampserver

When I click Debug Project in Netbeans, my browser opens a page, the URL looks like this:

```
http://localhost/projectname/?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug
```

The page has a directory listing of my project, but `http://localhost/projectname` is not the correct URL for my project.

The correct URL is in this format: `projectname.local`

How to get netbeans to load the correct address, I assume `projectname.local/?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug` when click debug project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I just figured it out. You have to change the Project URL:

1. Click your project in the Projects window.
2. Right click and select properties
3. Click Run Configuration
4. Set the correct Project URL
5. Click OK

https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/project-setup.html